# What is the right way to create a CloudSolrClient with Kerberos Delegation?

Tags: solr, kerberos, solrj, solrcloud, kerberos-delegation

Firstly, I would like to check if my understanding is correct on how this should be implemented.

After reading the [Solr 6.6.0 Kerberos Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/kerberos-authentication-plugin.html#KerberosAuthenticationPlugin-DelegationTokenswithSolrJ) (I've included some code snippets below) I believe I would need to create an initial CloudSolrClient to retrieve the token from Solr, by passing the cloudSolrClient to the `getDelegationToken(...)` method.

```
private String getDelegationToken(final String renewer, final String user, HttpSolrClient solrClient) throws Exception {
    DelegationTokenRequest.Get get = new DelegationTokenRequest.Get(renewer) {
      @Override
      public SolrParams getParams() {
        ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams(super.getParams());
        params.set("user", user);
        return params;
      }
    };
    DelegationTokenResponse.Get getResponse = get.process(solrClient);
    return getResponse.getDelegationToken();
  }
```

It then looks like I need to create another CloudSolrClient object that take a `HttpSolrClient` with the token retrieved above:

```
CloudSolrClient client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder()
            .withZkHost("http://localhost:2181")
            .withLBHttpSolrClientBuilder(new LBHttpSolrClient.Builder()
                .withResponseParser(client.getParser())
                .withHttpSolrClientBuilder(
                    new HttpSolrClient.Builder()
                        .withKerberosDelegationToken(token)
                ))
                    .build();
```

My first question with the code above is the `client.getParser()` - client hasn't been initialized, how is it possible to use it here?

Also where I have multiple users, according to the above code, I would have to create two `CloudSolrClient` objects for each user? The first to retrieve the token `getDelegationToken` and the second object to query Solr with the token provided `new CloudSolrClient.Builder() .... .withKerberosDelegationToken(token)`. **Update:** I may be able to reuse the SolrClient used to retrieve tokens.

Finally, I don't understand how the renewer works - I understand a token can expire and has to be renewed but how does passing a String as a renewer help renew tokens and what should this string be? I'd be grateful if someone can point me towards to some useful documentation or provide a clear explanation how how this works. 
**Update:** I may be wrong but for the renewer should the value be "zookeeper" I found out from documentation [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/solr-ref-guide/src/kerberos-authentication-plugin.adoc#using-delegation-tokens) that zookeeper is used store and manage the token information.